# Merge two python dictionaries on the same key and value

Tags: python

For example I have two dictionaries d1 and d2

```
d1 = {'a': ['b','c'], 'd': ['e', 'f']}
d2 = {'b':[1, 2], 'c': [3, 4], 'd': [5, 6], 'e': [7, 8], 'f': [9, 10]}
```

I expect a new dictionary d3 that looks like

```
d3 = {'a':{'b':[1, 2], 'c': [3, 4]}, 'd': {'e': [7, 8], 'f': [9, 10]}}
```

I have tried all kinds of looping but it does not work.

Comment: `d3 = {key: {value: d2[value] for value in d1[key]} for key in d1}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [dict comprehension](https://peps.python.org/pep-0274/) -

```
d1 = {'a': ['b','c'], 'd': ['e', 'f']}
d2 = {'b':[1, 2], 'c': [3, 4], 'd': [5, 6], 'e': [7, 8], 'f': [9, 10]}
d3 = {k1:{v:d2[v] for v in v1} for k1, v1 in d1.items()}
print(d3)
```

**Output:**

```
{'a': {'b': [1, 2], 'c': [3, 4]}, 'd': {'e': [7, 8], 'f': [9, 10]}}
```

Here, for every key(`k1`) in `d1`, we are creating an entry in `d3` and the corresponding value is another dict, where key is values from first dict and corresponding value in `d2` for the key.

Comment: thank you so much this is exactly what I am looking for I love you Jay

Comment: hey I am trying to put a try-except block for a KeyError, how do I do it with dict comprehension? Tried a def function still could not do it.. Thanks!!!

Comment: You cannot handle exceptions in the dict comprehension, you can either convert the dict comprehension into a for loop and then handle the exceptions there. Are you getting KeyError while doing `d2[v]`? You can replace it with `d2.get(v, [])` instead which return an empty list in case a `v` is not present in `d2`.

Comment: I made it like this and I think it worked:`


d3= dict()
for k1, v1 in d1.items():
    try:
        d3[k1] = {}
        for v in v1:
            d3[k1][v] = d2[v]
    except KeyError as e:
        print(e)

Comment: also thanks for answering!! do you have social media?